# Tensorflow Keras with multiple inputs improving accuracy and using estimators?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tf.keras

I'm working on creating a surrogate model for some abaqus models base on Aluminum testing. I have 5 input parameters and 1 output parameter. I have 1000 rows of data for training and 20 rows of data for evaluating and showing prediction accuracy. I am having trouble getting the model to give me accurate predictions. I've tried a few things and would appreciate any suggestions.

Here is the base code for my functional api model.

```
#Model Generation
input0 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
input1 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
input2 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
input3 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
input4 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
merged = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([input0, input1, input2, input3, input4])
dense1 = keras.layers.Dense(5, input_dim=5, activation='relu')(merged)
output = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')(dense1)
model = keras.Model(inputs=[input0, input1, input2, input3, input4], outputs=[output])

#Model Summary and Print
model.summary()
#keras.utils.plot_model(model, "model.png")
#Need to install things to plot

#Compile the Model
model.compile(
    loss='mse',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=["mae"]
)

#Train Model
model.fit([in_array_0, in_array_1, in_array_2, in_array_3, in_array_4],out_array, batch_size=32, epochs=500
       #,callbacks=keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', min_delta=1e-2, patience=5, 
       verbose=0)
         )

#Evaluate
model.evaluate([saved_in_array_0, saved_in_array_1, saved_in_array_2, saved_in_array_3, 
saved_in_array_4],saved_out_array, verbose=2)

#save model
model.save('Al_Total_Surrogate_5-14-2021_adam.h5')
del model
model = load_model('Al_Total_Surrogate_5-14-2021_adam.h5')

#Test
predictions = model.predict([saved_in_array_0, saved_in_array_1, saved_in_array_2, saved_in_array_3, 
saved_in_array_4])
print ("Input 0:", saved_in_array_0)
print ("Input 1:", saved_in_array_1)
print ("Input 2:", saved_in_array_2)
print ("Input 3:", saved_in_array_3)
print ("Input 4:", saved_in_array_4)
print ("predictions:", predictions)
print ("Actual:", saved_out_array)

for i in range(20):
    val = predictions[i]
    Per_Error = abs(val-saved_out_array[i])/saved_out_array[i]*100
    print("Predicted:  ", val, "  Actual: ", saved_out_array[i], "  Percent Error:  ", Per_Error)

#File
RESULTSFILE = 'Al_Total_Surrogate_5-14-2021_adam.txt'

with open(RESULTSFILE, mode='w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    csv_writer.writerow(['Epoch:  500'])
    csv_writer.writerow(['Batch:  10'])
    csv_writer.writerow(['Layers:  2'])
    csv_writer.writerow(['Layer 1:  relu'])
    csv_writer.writerow(['Layer 2:  relu'])
    csv_writer.writerow(['Optimizer:  adam'])
    for i in range(20):
        val = predictions[i]
        Per_Error = abs(val-saved_out_array[i])/saved_out_array[i]*100
        csv_writer.writerow(['Predicted:  ', val, '  Actual:  ', saved_out_array[i], '  Percent 
                             Error:  ', Per_Error])
```

Below are the results from the above code.

```
Predicted:   [188.32097]   Actual:  224.7629395   Percent Error:   [16.213514]

Predicted:   [153.02399]   Actual:  163.6922913   Percent Error:   [6.517292]

Predicted:   [184.92519]   Actual:  171.8843994   Percent Error:   [7.5869517]

Predicted:   [153.99652]   Actual:  184.1511993   Percent Error:   [16.374956]

Predicted:   [170.86081]   Actual:  198.1195374   Percent Error:   [13.758728]

Predicted:   [167.84995]   Actual:  184.6322632   Percent Error:   [9.089591]

Predicted:   [175.9255]   Actual:  202.3720093   Percent Error:   [13.068262]

Predicted:   [217.255]   Actual:  204.0169067   Percent Error:   [6.488726]

Predicted:   [222.72789]   Actual:  210.9862366   Percent Error:   [5.565128]

Predicted:   [161.50806]   Actual:  199.8728027   Percent Error:   [19.19458]

Predicted:   [208.30794]   Actual:  175.3465271   Percent Error:   [18.797869]

Predicted:   [213.59142]   Actual:  183.5816803   Percent Error:   [16.346804]

Predicted:   [172.13594]   Actual:  175.7514648   Percent Error:   [2.0571802]

Predicted:   [196.41121]   Actual:  174.9219208   Percent Error:   [12.285074]

Predicted:   [182.2879]   Actual:  215.4689026   Percent Error:   [15.399438]

Predicted:   [200.62784]   Actual:  158.2305145   Percent Error:   [26.794657]

Predicted:   [206.18555]   Actual:  198.1768951   Percent Error:   [4.0411634]

Predicted:   [192.50092]   Actual:  195.0370026   Percent Error:   [1.3003107]

Predicted:   [159.96469]   Actual:  177.1092072   Percent Error:   [9.680195]

Predicted:   [220.8257]   Actual:  196.6077118   Percent Error:   [12.317924]
```

The model seems a bit random and I'm having issues making it converge to a mean below 10% error. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

I also generated a sequential model for this about a year ago which provided very accurate results. I need to get functional api to work because I am trying to expand to 10 inputs for a similar problem.

Here is the sequential. How would I move over the estimator to the functional api?

```
########## Defining Base Model ##########

def baseline_model():
    #creat model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(5, input_dim=5, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
    #compile model
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
    filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
    #pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))
    return model



########## Seeding and Estimation ##########

# fix the random seed for reproducibility
seed = 10
np.random.seed(seed)

'''
    This seed sets the randomability of the function to a number.
    This way if you created multiple models they would all be based off the
    same randominess.
'''



########## Create the Pipeline ##########

# The pipeline is the model in this case
estimators = []
estimators.append(('standardize', StandardScaler()))
estimators.append(('mlp', KerasRegressor(build_fn=baseline_model, epochs=5000, batch_size=10, 
verbose=0)))
pipeline = Pipeline(estimators)
epoch=5000
batch=10


######### Evaluate the Model ##########

'''
    This just tells you how good of a model it could create.
    We end up using the saved model later in the fit section.
'''

kfold = KFold(n_splits=10)
#kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
results = cross_val_score(pipeline, inn, out, cv=kfold)
print("Results:  %.2f (%.2f) MSE" % (results.mean(), results.std()))



######### Fit the Pipeline ##########

my_model = pipeline.fit(inn, out)
```